# Microsoft Dynamics 365 Guides - Not able to sign in

Tags: dynamics-365, windows-mixed-reality

I have installed Microsoft Dynamics 365 Guides (Preview) in Windows 10 Pro 1803 via Microsoft Store App.

I'm planning to use this PC application for Authoring a guide.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/mixed-reality/guides/pc-authoring

And I have followed this document for Sign Up https://dynamics.microsoft.com/en-us/get-started/mixed-reality/guides/

But, when I tried to sign-in, The following pop-up shows.[image]

Note that, I'm behind corporate proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics 365 Guides are for Hololens devices only. They don't work on desktop.

Comment: Plan is to use PC application for authoring a guide

Comment: Is your account that you are trying to sign in signed up for the preview?

Comment: Yes, the account I'm using is signed up for the preview

Comment: I created a new Azure user, and was trying to add Dynamics 365 Guides Preview Trial to it.  But after signing in I got the following message.  
   "" The offer that you want is unavailable. This might be caused by one of the following reasons:
The offer has expired.
The service is not available in your country or region.
You cannot sign up for the same trial a second time. ""